# Slowing Audio Playback in Android

Tags: android, performance, audio, playback, slowdown

I'm making an Android application where I need to slow down the audio being played so the user can hear the sentences clearer.  I have no idea how to approach this.  While I do know a little about signal processing I do not know how to incorporate that with the Android.  Are there any APIs or something that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want. There is a method for setting the playback rate, here ->
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setPlaybackRate(int)

Comment: Okay but AudioTracks are really confusing for me and I'm having a hard to fitting them into my code.  Does the MediaPlayer class have an AUX effect that slows playback rate?  Otherwise can you point me out to a page that better explains AudioTracks?  Thanks